# Excel VBA: compute an approximate interest rate of a french amortization schedule given: Starting Principal, Periodic Payment Amount, Nr Of Years

Tags: c#, excel, vba, rate, amortization

I need to compute (approximately) the interest rate of a french amortization schedule (a series of equal payments at regular intervals) given:

- the Starting Principal
- the Periodic Payment Amount (Principal And Interests)
- the Nr Of Years of the amortization plan.

There is no direct/easy way to compute the interest rate with a mathematical formula, and I disliked the RATE excel formula ( https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RATE-function-9f665657-4a7e-4bb7-a030-83fc59e748ce ) because I need some code easily portable in other languages (I'm currently developing a C# library to do some financial calculations).

Some Wikipedia references for Amortization follows:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_schedule
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_%28business%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should make no substantial difference to offer the computation only for annual interest. In fact, from yearly to monthly, the difference of interest is circa 0,005 for 10 years and 0,0025 for 30 years.

The Excel VBA code follows, and if someone has any suggestion to improve it, you are welcome.

```
' compute the Annual Interest Rate of a french amortization schedule (a series of equal payments at regular intervals) given:
' > the Starting Principal
' > the Periodic Payment Amount (Principal And Interests)
' > the Yearly Nr Of payments
' > the Total Nr Of payments
'
' returns the interest truncated to 2 decimals (for 7,525% returns 0,0752)
' returns Null if the interest rate is not computable
'
' examples:
' > the Starting Principal = 10000
' > the Periodic Payment Amount (Principal And Interests) = 1423.78
' > the Yearly Nr Of payments = 1
' > the Total Nr Of payments = 10
' >>> returns 0,07   (i.e. 7%)
'
' uses the functions:
' > ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan

'
Public Function ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan(StartingPrincipal, PeriodicPaymentAmountPrincipalAndInterests, NrOfYearlyPayments, NrOfTotalPayments)

Dim IMin, IMax, AComputed, LoopLevel, LoopCount, LoopIIncrement, LoopICurrent, LoopFloorI, LoopFloorA, DebugLoopCounter

    IMin = (0.00001) / 100
    IMax = (99.99999) / 100

    ' Compute the Annuity (the Periodic Payment Amount) with the minimum rate
    AComputed = ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan(IMin, NrOfYearlyPayments, NrOfTotalPayments, StartingPrincipal)

    ' if the given "Periodic Payment Amount" is equal to the computed Annuity returns the interest rate used for the computation
    If PeriodicPaymentAmountPrincipalAndInterests = AComputed Then
        ' returns IMin
        ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan = IMin
        ' exit from the function
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Returns Error Value (Null) if the given "Periodic Payment Amount" is less than the computed Annuity
    If PeriodicPaymentAmountPrincipalAndInterests < AComputed Then
        ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan = Null
        Exit Function
    End If



    ' Compute the Annuity (the Periodic Payment Amount) with the maximum rate
    AComputed = ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan(IMax, NrOfYearlyPayments, NrOfTotalPayments, StartingPrincipal)

    ' if the given "Periodic Payment Amount" is equal to the computed Annuity returns the interest rate used for the computation
    If PeriodicPaymentAmountPrincipalAndInterests = AComputed Then
        ' returns IMax
        ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan = IMax
        ' exit from the function
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Returns Error Value (Null) if the given "Periodic Payment Amount" is greater than the computed Annuity
    If PeriodicPaymentAmountPrincipalAndInterests > AComputed Then
        ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan = Null
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' loop
    '
    ' loop steps:
    ' 1> from IMin, increments of 0,05
    ' 2> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,02
    ' 3> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,005
    ' 4> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,0005
    ' 5> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,00005
    '
    ' set the counter to the first level
    LoopLevel = 1


    ' reset the loop counter to count loop cycles needed to find the rate (deactivate this in production)
    DebugLoopCounter = 0

    ' loop to find the rate
    Do

        ' test the loop level
        Select Case LoopLevel
            ' Level 1> from IMin, increments of 0,05
            Case 1

                ' set loop parameters
                LoopIIncrement = 0.05
                LoopICurrent = IMin

            ' Level 2> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,02
            Case 2

                ' set loop parameters
                LoopIIncrement = 0.02
                LoopICurrent = LoopFloorI

            ' Level 3> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,005
            Case 3

                ' set loop parameters
                LoopIIncrement = 0.005
                LoopICurrent = LoopFloorI

            ' Level 4> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,0005
            Case 4

                ' set loop parameters
                LoopIIncrement = 0.0005
                LoopICurrent = LoopFloorI

            ' Level 5> from the floor rate computed in the previous step, increments of 0,00005
            Case 5

                ' set loop parameters
                LoopIIncrement = 0.00005
                LoopICurrent = LoopFloorI

            ' exit from the loop and return the last rate
            Case 6

                ' returns LoopICurrent truncated to 2 decimals
                ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan = Fix(LoopICurrent * 10000) / 10000
                ' exit from the function
                Exit Function

        End Select

        ' loop until the computed Annuity is not greater than the given "Periodic Payment Amount"
        Do

            ' increments the debug counter
            DebugLoopCounter = DebugLoopCounter + 1

            ' increments the current interest rate
            LoopICurrent = LoopICurrent + LoopIIncrement

            ' compute the Annuity with the current rate
            AComputed = ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan(LoopICurrent, NrOfYearlyPayments, NrOfTotalPayments, StartingPrincipal)

            ' if the given "Periodic Payment Amount" is equal to the computed Annuity returns the interest rate used for the computation
            If PeriodicPaymentAmountPrincipalAndInterests = AComputed Then
                ' returns LoopICurrent
                ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan = LoopICurrent
                ' exit from the function
                Exit Function
            End If

            ' if the computed Annuity is grater than the given "Periodic Payment Amount" exit loop
            If AComputed > PeriodicPaymentAmountPrincipalAndInterests Then

                ' exit loop
                Exit Do

            ' if the computed Annuity is less than the given "Periodic Payment Amount" save Floor rate and exit loop
            Else

                ' save Floor rate
                LoopFloorA = AComputed
                LoopFloorI = LoopICurrent

            End If

        ' END - loop until the computed Annuity is not greater than the given "Periodic Payment Amount"
        Loop

        ' increments the loop level counter
        LoopLevel = LoopLevel + 1

    ' END - loop to find the rate
    Loop

End Function



' compute the Periodic Payment Amount (Principal And Interests)(la rata periodica) of a french amortization schedule (a series of equal payments at regular intervals) given:
' > the Annual Interest Rate
' > the Yearly Nr Of payments
' > the Total Nr Of payments
' > the Starting Principal
'
' returns the Periodic Payment Amount, made of Principal And Interests
'
' examples:
' > the Annual Interest Rate = 0.07   (7%)
' > the Nr Of payments = 120
' > the Starting Principal = 10000
' >>> returns 1423,77502727365
'
' used by:
' > ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan

'
Public Function ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan(AnnualInterestRate, NrOfYearlyPayments, NrOfTotalPayments, StartingPrincipal)
' Starting principal 10.000, Annual interest rate 0.07 (7%), 120 total payments, 1 payments for year, Periodic Payment Amount 1.423,78
Dim i, nt, ny, p, A

    i = AnnualInterestRate
    nt = NrOfTotalPayments
    ny = NrOfYearlyPayments
    p = StartingPrincipal

    ' calcola la rata iniziale (la formula funziona con qualunque durata e periodicità)
    A = p * (i / ny) / (1 - (1 / (1 + (i / ny)) ^ nt))

    ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan = A

End Function



Sub test()
Dim Result

    'Result = ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan(10000, 1423.78, 1, 10)    ' result 7%
    Result = ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan(10000, 116.1, 12, 120)      ' result 7%
    'Result = ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan(10000, 9700, 1, 10)   ' result 96,89%
    'Result = ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan(10000, 900, 1, 10)   ' error, annuity less than the minimum allowed
    'Result = ComputeIRateConstPaymLoan(10000, 100000000, 1, 10)   ' error, annuity greater than the maximum allowed
    '
    'Result = ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan(0.07, 1, 10, 10000)   ' result 1423,77502727365
    'Result = ComputePeriodicPaymentAmountWInterestConstPaymConstRateLoan(0.07, 12, 120, 10000)   ' result 116,108479218624

    If IsNull(Result) Then
        MsgBox "Errore"
    Else
        Debug.Print Result
        Debug.Print Result * 1000
    End If

End Sub
```